# Inserting a row of zeros every nth row into a multi index pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the one below

```py
          h1  h2  h3
c1 a1 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
   a2 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
c2 a1 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
   a2 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
c3 a1 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
   a2 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
```

I would like to add a row of zeros every nth row while preserving the order. For example, if n=2 the results should look like

```py
          h1  h2  h3
c1 a1 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
       g   0   0   0
   a2 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
       g   0   0   0
c2 a1 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
       g   0   0   0
   a2 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
       g   0   0   0
c3 a1 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
       g   0   0   0
   a2 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
       g   0   0   0
```

I want to be able to do this regardless of how many levels the multi index has.

Comment: kindly provide the input dataframe as a dictionary : ``df.to_dict()``

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0], df.index.levels[1],
['i1', 'i2', 'g']]),fill_value=0)
print(df)
```

output:

```
          h1  h2  h3
c1 a1 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
      g    0   0   0
   a2 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
      g    0   0   0
c2 a1 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
      g    0   0   0
   a2 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
      g    0   0   0
c3 a1 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
      g    0   0   0
   a2 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
      g    0   0   0
```

**EDITING AFTER THE COMMENTS TO MY ANSWER:**

```
allTheLevels = [eval(f"df.index.levels[{x}]").tolist() for x in range(int(df.index.nlevels))]
allTheLevels[-1] = allTheLevels[-1] + ['g']
df = df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(allTheLevels),fill_value=1)
print(df)
```

output:

```
          h1  h2  h3
c1 a1 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
      g    1   1   1
   a2 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
      g    1   1   1
c2 a1 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
      g    1   1   1
   a2 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
      g    1   1   1
c3 a1 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
      g    1   1   1
   a2 i1   0   0   0
      i2   0   0   0
      g    1   1   1
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great, but I still need to know before hand the values and order of ['i1', 'i2', 'g'].

Comment: No. df = df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0], df.index.levels[1],
df.index.levels[2].tolist()+['g']]),fill_value=0)

Comment: One issue with this approach is that you still need to know the number of levels from the multiindex, i.e. [d.index.levels[0], d.index.levels[1], d.index.levels[-1].tolist()+['gh']] This would work with three levels but it's going to change the structure if the multiindex has two levels

Comment: "No" again. Everything is possible, you just need to open your mind to programming. Look at the Edit I did on the answer now.